# Image processing using visual C++ without using OpenCv

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I wanted to know whether I can work on images using Visual C++ without using OpenCV? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express on Windows 7 (32-bit system).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can, obviously... But I can't see a reason to do that.

Comment: Yes, of course you can. You can write code to do whatever you want. OpenCV is just code too ;-) Perhaps there is something in particular you mean when you say *"work on images"*? Perhaps edit your question to explain a bit more about what you want to do and you may get some helpful answers.